# Nginx - preventing slow HTTP DoS attacks

Tags: apache, security, nginx

I need to preventing slow HTTP DoS attacks on Nginx. I usually use following configuration on Apache, using mod_reqtimeout:

```
<IfModule mod_reqtimeout.c>
  RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,MinRate=500 body=20,MinRate=500
</IfModule>
```

How to do it using Nginx?

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-ddos-attacks-with-nginx-and-nginx-plus/ (aka the first result when you Google for _"nginx slow http dos attack"_).

Comment: @robertklep thank you, but I need to know how to convert exactly my Apache configuration (the one that I wrote above) to Nginx configuration.

Comment: Well, since NGINX isn't Apache, there's a big chance that you won't be able to convert the Apache configuration _exactly_.

Comment: Take a look at `client_header_timeout` and `client_body_timeout`. But I guess, it's impossible to get exactly the same config.